# Got stuck on an implementation of the HashMap Collection

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

```
Question:
```

Ask user to enter a string and use Map collection to compute the number of times of the letters and digits. If encountering any other characters, use asterisk * to display on the console.

Example: 
Input String:aaaabbbcccddd1112233^^^
Output format: *(3),1(3),2(2),3(2),a(4),b(3),c(3),d(3) (note: character(number of times))

I have hard time on display asterisk on the console while other characters are entered. Can anyone give me some hints?

```
   import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class Test5 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Scanner Input
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Give me a String: ");
            String line = sc.nextLine();

            //String -> charArray
            char[] array = line.toCharArray();

            //create HashMap object
            HashMap<Character,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();


            //Travese the array and put it in HashMap
            for(Character c : array) {
                if(!hm.containsKey(c)) {
                    if(c == 97) {
                        hm.put(c, 1);
                    }

                } else  {
                    hm.put(c, hm.get(c) + 1);
                } 
            }

            //get the key 
            Set<Character> key = hm.keySet();

            //print
            for(Character ch: key) {
                System.out.println(ch + "(" + hm.get(ch) + ")");
            }



        }

    }
```

Comment: The algorithm should thus be: if current character is a digit or a letter, increment the count for that character. Otherwise, increment the count for the asterisk character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static boolean isLetterOrDigit(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ||
            (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ||
            (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputString = "blabla!!123";

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (char c : inputString.toCharArray()) {
        if (!isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            c = '*';
        }
        map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    }

    for (Character ch : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(ch + "(" + map.get(ch) + ")");
    }
}
```

Easy bonus: If you replace the HashMap with a TreeMap your output also get's sorted.

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Comment: The Java Character class has s bunch of utilities for classifying characters including `isLetter()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: @DanAllen I know. But those match more than [a..zA..Z]. So I doubt that's what the OP wants.

Comment: And I'd say that definition fails internationalisation standards. I don't know the OPs purpose or language for that matter. If you like you can use `getType()` and pick the categories out of that (e.g. `LOWERCASE_LETTER`). I do think it's time we stopped thinking in ASCII and writing code that only works for English.

Comment: @DanAllen You have a point when talking about code that might eventually be used internationally. But when I'm writing code for a local project I usually don't care that it won't work for people that are never going to use it in the first place :)

Comment: It might suit your purpose and even your current purpose. But I do think that examples on this site should guide people to best practice and that isn't on a Unicode platform teaching people to think in terms of "lowecase letters are between characters 'a' and 'z'. It may well suit Danny Chang too. But it's obviously a learning exercise for him and he should go away understanding Unicode better. So few programmers do.

Comment: @DanAllen Interesting point of view. Perhaps you should post an answer with a working example using those functions. I'll even upvote it if it actually does what we expect. Until then I'm not going to waste my time getting ad-hoc programs to work internationally :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer ripped off from Imus that works internationally.

The internationalisation works by getting the 'Unicode Category' of the character and checking to see if it's a letter or decimal digit.

This code works for most living languages and will pass internationalisation standards for most organisations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputString = "Non-naïve code handles ß 1234";

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (char c : inputString.toCharArray()) {
        int type=Character.getType(c);
        if (type!=Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER && 
            type!=Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER &&
            type!=Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER
        ) {
            c = '*';
        }
        map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    }

    for (Character ch : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(ch + "(" + map.get(ch) + ")");
    }
}
```

An alternative way of checking if something is a letter is `Character.isLetter(c)` but that may include things you don't consider to be a letter which may or may not (usually not) be a problem.

I'm posting this because an important feature of Java is that it has native support for Unicode but too many programmers don't understand it.
I've seen way too much code in supposedly international organisations that can't handle anything outside ASCII. It's just rude to be unable to accept a customer's name is Helmut Maaß.

Java only really offers great support for The Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane. Though as mentioned that supports most living languages!

If you want to go full Unicode you get it the following shizzle.
It has to work in 'code-points' because some Unicode "characters" can't be represented by a single Java character.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int MYSTERY=28;//Hmmmm....
    String inputString = "\ud83d\ude00\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude0f\ud83d\ude4c\ud83d\ude40";
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();//Not from Character. We need an integer to store code-points.

    for (int i=0;i<inputString.length();) {
        int cp=inputString.codePointAt(i);//May read 2 characters to identify a code-point in a supplementary plane.
        int type=Character.getType(cp);//Works fine. Overloaded to handle code-points.
        int c;//We need to remember the original code-point for later...
        if (type!=Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER && 
            type!=Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER &&
            type!=Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER &&
            type!=MYSTERY //Whaaat???
        ) {
            System.out.println(type);
            c = '*';
        }else{
            c=cp;
        }
        map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
        i+=Character.charCount(cp);//If we used 2 characters move on 2 or otherwise 1.
    }

    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer,Integer> curr : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.print(Character.toChars(curr.getKey()));//Gets us back to characters from code-points...
        System.out.print("(" + curr.getValue() + ")");
    }
}
```

Which is going too far for homework I suggest. 
What's happening here is that characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane of Unicode have to be represented as 32-bit integers rather than 16-bit native characters of Java.

Comment: Nice answer. I hope the OP selects this as the accepted one! You deserve it :)

Comment: @Imus. Thanks. I upvoted yours as credit for stealing it. Make sure to run the new version if you can't already work out what it does. People think Unicode is boring but there's some neat stuff in there if you know where to look....

Answer (score 0):

```
final String lowerLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
final String upperLetters = lowerLetters.toUpperCase();
final String digits = "0123456789";
final String lettersDigits = lowerLetters + upperLetters + digits;

String line = sc.nextLine();

Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
    if (lettersDigits.indexOf(c) == -1) {
        c = '*';
    }
    Integer count = map.get(c);
    if (count == null) {
        count = 0;
    }
    map.put(c,++count);
}

for(Entry<Character,Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + "(" + e.getValue() + ")");
}
```

Comment: You can use `map.getOrDefault(c, 0)` for the current count. And you missed the character in `map.put(c,count++)`. Also `lettersDigits.contains(""+c)` looks cleaner than `index == -1`

Comment: Just figured that `map.put(c, count++)` will never increase the actual count. Should be `map.put(c, ++count)`.

Comment: The Java Character class has s bunch of utilities for classifying characters including `isLetter()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html